# Solving a large equation system involving reciprocals

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I have this equation system, I am wondering if this is possible to solve in feasible time. And what are the methods to solve it?

We have 100 unknowns $x_i$, $i=1,2...100$

And 100 equations all of this form $j=1,2...100$

$I_j=\sum_{i\in N_j}c_i\sum_{n\in M_i} 1/(\sum_{m\in S_n} x_m)$

Here $N,M,S$ are known sets of cardinality around $5,5,20$ respectively (on average). I and c are known constants.

Comment: Do your N,M,S follow some pattern or are they just random index sets?

Comment: Pretty random..

Comment: Multiplying each equation with all the denominators should yield you a system of (pretty ugly) polynomial equations you can then solve numerically, which should be feasible if the system isn't too big. I don't know if other options are possible.

Comment: How do you do that? Which method?

Comment: suppose the $i$ in $x_i$ is unrelated to that in $M_i$ : if so better to use a different index.